# HTML Get input group text next to input box with input group?

Tags: html, css, flask, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

so I am running bootstrap here. I am trying to get my form to look like this:
[image] (But instead of having them on the same row, I want them spaced out on each line.)

Here is what my modal currently looks like:
[image]

Please note, I can't change my bootstrap versions, as it will cause dysfunctionality on my site.

my code:

```
{% extends "_base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
        <h1 class="h3 mb-3 fw-normal text-center">Add funds into balance</h1><br>
        <div class="form-floating">
            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" onclick="crypto">USDT-TRX</a>
            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <div class="col-11">
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Payment with USDT-TRC20</h4>
                    </div>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss= "modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    
                    <h5>Amount to deposit:</h5>
                    <form>
                      <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-xs-4">
                      <div class="input-group-append"><div class="input-group-text">USD&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div><input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <span class="input-group-text">USDT-TRC20&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name"></span>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Create Invoice</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
{% endblock %}
```

base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>mysite</title>
    <!-- meta -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <!-- styles -->
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename="styles.css")}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
    {% block css %}{% endblock %}
  </head>
  <body>

    {% include "navigation.html" %}

    <div class="container">

      <br>

      <!-- messages -->
      {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
      {% if messages %}
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          {% for category, message in messages %}
          <div class="alert alert-{{ category }} alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
           {{message}}
           <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
      </div>
      {% endif %}
      {% endwith %}

      <!-- child template -->
      {% block content %}{% endblock %}

    </div>

    <!-- scripts -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    {% block js %}{% endblock %}

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: As you can see, my USD text box is way too big, and so is my USDT-TRX box. It's supposed to be small like the picture above to compliment the input box.